# Существует ли алгоритм хождения по часовой стрелке на дискретном поле

Tags: алгоритм, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Есть игровое поле как на картинке, гриб осуществляет движение только в одном из 4 направлений, есть такой алгоритм, который описывает движения гриба по часовой стрелке на поле при том условии, что поле постоянно меняется? Препятствия появляются новые, поэтому движение по заложенному маршруту не подходит.
[image: игровое поле]

Answer (score 2):

Раз поле меняется, то на каждом шаге придётся проверять возможность хода по очереди в направлении:

- налево от текущего направления
- затем текущего
- направо
- разворот

Если текущее направление описывается вектором `(dx, dy)`, то налево `(-dy, dx)`, направо `(dy, -dx)`, для остальных направлений должно быть понятно